# How do i customize an app icon? (Windows 11)

Tags: windows, windows-11

I want to change to app icon on my browser, but when i put a 256x256 image in a folder(even without a folder I tried), when I clicked to browse images and went to it, it wouldn't show any possible icons.

Nothing happened, wouldn't show. Assuming the image is supposed to be in dll, so I tried opening a dll. On opening the dll file in notepad, a bunch of random stuff. Opening it in my browser just made me download a file I couldn't open.

After this, as someone told me, I resized the image to 32x32 as well as 16x16. I put them in the same folder as 256x256. I clicked browse to change the app icon once again, and  as expected, no possible icons once again.

Comment: Let's say your browser is Chrome. Do you want to change the Chrome icon? Is this what is all about?

Answer (score 1):

An image is not an icon. The icon is a specialized file format whose
extension is `.ico`.

For more information, see Wikipedia
[ICO (file format)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_(file_format)).

For creating an icon you need an "icon editor".
For example, you could use the free
[Greenfish Icon Editor Pro](http://greenfishsoftware.org/gfie.php#apage).

This program can read an image via its menu
*File > Batch convert files...*,
open them in the editor, improve the icon and finally save it as an
`.ico` file.

Note that an icon file can include multiple copies of the icon,
in more than one resolution, to be used various desktop
sizes/resolutions.